# Django - How to retrieve an object from a custom template tag?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-voting

I'm without clues on solving this problem.

I've a template tag that receives an Object:

```
{% score_for_object OBJECT_HERE as score2 %}
```

The problem is that I'm passing to the template a context that came from a raw select:

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("select ...") 
comments = utils.dictfetchall(cursor)
```

To solve the problem of the template tag that accepts a Django object, I've write a template tag:

```
'''
This template tag is used to transform a comment_id in an object to use in the django-voting app
'''
def retrive_comment_object(comment_id):
    from myapp.apps.comments.models import MPTTComment
    return MPTTComment.objects.get(id=comment_id)
```

With this template tag I expected this to work:

```
{% for item in comments %}
    {% score_for_object item.comment_id|retrieve_comment_object as score2 %}

    {{ score2.score }} {# expected to work, but not working #}
{% endfor %}
```

My question. It is possible to retrieve an object from a template tag?

Best Regards,

Comment: Do you want only score to be pass in that tag?

Answer (score 2):

To get the score:

```
from django import template
from myapp.apps.comments.models import MPTTComment

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def retrive_comment_object(comment_id):
    data = MPTTComment.objects.get(id=comment_id)
    return data.score


{% for item in comments %}
    Score: {% retrive_comment_object item.comment_id %}
{% endfor %}
```